# FLUSHBAR: anyone familiar with this package, how to create a form within?

Tags: forms, flutter, package

maybe I am overstressing this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar), but the last example shows a form. However, my implementation shows no sign of life. Not even an error or warning.

My approach is a little different. I want to create a form with multiple, different input widgets (text, button, selector) and then return those with a bloc event. The returning/saving part is not yet implemented.

If someone has implemented a form with flushbar, I would appreciate any advice.

This is my flushbar code

```dart
 Widget otherActionsSlider() {
    bool paused;
    int priority;
    bool supply;
    return Flushbar(
      userInputForm : Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget> [
              Text("progress"),
              _DelayStatusFormField(
                
                onSaved: (value) => this.delayStatus = value,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  _DelayFormField(
                    onSaved: (value) => this.delay = value,
                    enabled: this.delayStatus == DelayStatus.unrecoverable ? true : false
                  )
                ],
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Submit'),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (this._formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    setState(() {
                      this._formKey.currentState.save();
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),

        ],),)),
    );
  }
```

and the form field classes

```dart
class _DelayStatusFormField extends FormField<DelayStatus> {
  _DelayStatusFormField({
    FormFieldSetter<DelayStatus> onSaved,
    FormFieldValidator<DelayStatus> validator,
    DelayStatus initialValue,
  }) : super(
      onSaved: onSaved,
      validator: validator,
      initialValue: initialValue,
      builder: (FormFieldState<DelayStatus> state) {
        return
            CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
                groupValue: initialValue == DelayStatus.recoverable ? 1 :
                    initialValue == DelayStatus.unrecoverable ? 2 : 0,
                children: {
                  0: Text('on time'),
                  1: Text('recoverable'),
                  2: Text('unrecoverable')
                },
                onValueChanged: (int val) => state.didChange(val == 0 ? DelayStatus.onTime :
                                                             val == 1 ? DelayStatus.recoverable :
                                                             DelayStatus.unrecoverable)
        );
      }
  );
}

class _DelayFormField extends FormField<int> {
  _DelayFormField({
    FormFieldSetter<int> onSaved,
    FormFieldValidator<int> validator,
    int initialValue,
    bool enabled
  }) : super(
      onSaved: onSaved,
      validator: validator,
      initialValue: initialValue,
      builder: (FormFieldState<int> state) {
        TextEditingController inputTec = TextEditingController(text: initialValue.toString());
        return
          CupertinoTextField(
            controller: inputTec,
            placeholder: 'delay in days',
            enabled: enabled
          );
      }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't yet fully implemented my solution, I finally received some signs of life. My issue was, the function returning the Flushbar has to be of type `Flushbar<List<String>>` given the example of the package readme. I returned `Widget` instead.

If someone tries to work with this example, there quite a few brackets and more importantly, it is not (as written in the readme) `Flushbar(userInputForm = Form(` but `Flushbar(userInputForm: Form(`

Though the quality of the example given leaves room for improvement, the widget itself is quite nice, especially when implementing more simple use cases (I have a CupertinoApp, so I cannot use snackbar)